# Why doesn't this background animate?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a simple challenge with a background not animating.

I have used this code before so I'm a bit scratching my head.

The code is:

html (it has a repeated background I can see).

```
<div id="working_wrap"></div>​
```

jquery:

```
$('#working_wrap').animate({backgroundPosition: '30px 0px'}, 5000);​
```

[I've created a jsfiddle of the simple problem](http://jsfiddle.net/w43LJ/). The background should start animating straight away.

What is my foggy brain missing right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#working_wrap').animate({backgroundPosition: 30},5000);
```

0px is useless (EDIT: in your case) and it is not supported by animate. From Jquery doc

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `px` after 0 I think.

So, `$('#working_wrap').animate({backgroundPosition: '30px 0'},5000);​`.
That will move the background after 5 seconds 30px to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example below. Set the background explicitly and also for firefox 2 you need to set the start background position

http://jsfiddle.net/w43LJ/4/

Answer (score 0):

`background-position` animation is not supported by default. Include a jQuery plugin called `jquery.backgroundPosition.js` to make it work:

http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/